# Php Stored date from MySQL db convert to equivalent Ethiopian date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to convert any Gregorian date to an equivalent Ethiopian Date. The Gregorian date is generated on records created or updated using the PHP date function, `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` from the server date. I want to show the changes made are in the Ethiopian date so the views are can easily understand it. I've made a function to change it. but the function date is not reliable in some leap years.

The function returns the date format in either Tigrigna or Amharic language.
Any hint?

```
function conver_to_ethiopian_date($date, $lang ="ti"){
$OFFSET=79372;
$DAY=86400;
$EYear=1745;
$EMonth=0;
$EDate=0;
$GC=0;
 $timezone  = 0; 
$tot= gmdate($date, 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
$days=round(strtotime($tot)/$DAY);
$days +=$OFFSET;
$mark=0;
$EYear=1745;
while ($mark==0){
    if ($EYear % 4 ==3){
        if ($days>=366) {
            $days-=366;
          $EYear=$EYear+1;
        }
        else{
          $mark=1;
        }
      }

    else{
          if ($days>=365){
              $days-=365;
              $EYear=$EYear+1;
            }
          else {$mark=1;}
        }
    }

  if ($days==0){
  $EYear-=1;
  //leap year
  $EMonth=12;
  $EDate=5 + (($EYear%4==3)?1:0);
}
else{
  $EMonth = (($days-1) / 30);
  if ($days % 30 ==0){ $EDate = 30;}
  else {$EDate=$days % 30;}
  
}

$months_am =array("መስከረም", "ጥቅምት", "ኅዳር", "ታኅሣሥ", "ጥር","የካቲት","መጋቢት","ሚያዝያ", "ግንቦት", "ሰኔ", "ሐምሌ", "ነሐሴ", 'ጳጉሜ');
$months_tg =array("መስከረም", "ጥቅምቲ", "ሕዳር", "ታሕሳስ", "ጥሪ","የካቲት","መጋቢት","ሚያዝያ", "ጉንበት", "ሰነ", "ሓምለ", "ነሓሰ", 'ጳጉሜን');
$days_am =array("እሁድ", "ሰኞ",  "ማክሰኞ",  "ሮብ",  "ሓሙስ", "ኣርብ", "ቀዳሜ");
$days_tg =array("ሰንበት", "ሶኒ",  "ሰሉስ",  "ረቡዕ",  "ሓሙስ", "ዓርቢ", "ቀዳም");
$date_time = explode(' - ', $date);

$year =$year?$year:date("Y") ;
 $day_of_week = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_time[1], $date_time[2], $date_time[0]));
  if ("am" == $lang)
 return $days_am[$day_of_week]." ".$months_am[$EMonth]." ".$EDate.", ".$EYear;
else
 return $days_tg[$day_of_week]." ".$months_tg[$EMonth]." ". $EDate.", ".$EYear;
}
```

Comment: I'm not much of a php programmer however [setlocale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) + [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) will probably acheive this directly.

Comment: Go with [Intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php) which works with any PHP build. (setlocale() is not thread safe)